# What's the ECB share of euro area gov debt?

Tags: macroeconomics, government-debt, open-economy-macro

Where can I see an evolution of the ECB's share in the market for Euro area governmental debt?

I would like to know if there's something similar happening in Euro area as is happening with [Fed's share of USA gov. debt](http://macromarketmusings.blogspot.pt/2016/08/the-unwinding-of-qe-has-begun.html).